# Cant't stop or kill mysql process and there is no installation to be found

Tags: homebrew, mysql

So I've tried installing mariadb and using the `mysql` command but I always get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock' (2)
```

If I uninstall mariadb and try using `mysql` I get:

```
command not found: mysql
```

If I then do `ps ax | grep mysql` I get this:

```
7809 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mysql
```

If I try killing it with the PID 7809 (This ID is changing every single time I run the command) I get this:

```
kill 7809 failed: no such process
```

I've deleted every single folder using [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x) tutorial but it didn't help. I don't have mysql in my mac system preferences so I can't uninstall it there. I have no clue what else to try. I also tried all kinds of Launchctl unloading but mostly I just get this error:

```
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
```

Every time I restart my mac and check what processes are running mysql is always there. Did anyone experience something similiar?

Comment: Did you try from Activity Monitor? What OS are you running?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm running MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1. I didn't try the Activity Monitor.

Comment: on Big Sur, I'd double-check where it all got installed to - it probably won't let you put random user stuff in the System partition. [I don't have access to Big Sur to test]

Comment: @Tetsujin how would I check that?

Comment: Without using terminal, which I'm not that great with, I'd look at [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) & set it to search 'sql' in invisible files, all local disks. It's slower than Spotlight, but is considerably more determined. Alternatively, Activity Monitor's 'inspect' will show the path

Comment: After reinstalling mariadb and doing this it's finally working https://serverfault.com/questions/291126/mysql-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-tables-table-mysql-host-doe

Comment: @Kris That question is about Windows how does that deal with a problem on macOS?

Comment: You should note that the "unkillable" process is actually your grep (obviously). not a copy of mysqld, so it was never actually running.  That would also be why the PID kept changing.